# How do I get a weekday 12 weeks ago using in a Google script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm having the following formula:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)-84
```

and this gives me Monday, 12 weeks ago.

I'm working on this code, but it gives me only a certain days back

```
var twelweWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(
  oneWeekAgo, 
  Session.getScriptTimeZone(),
  'yyyy-MM-dd'
);
```

Comment: You can multiply 7 times 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code does the same.

### Code

```
function getPastweeks(weeks) {
  var cDate = new Date();
  return new Date(cDate.getTime() - getMs(weeks) - getCorr(cDate.getDay()));
}

function getCorr(day) {
  return day >= 1 ? getMs(day - 1) / 7 : getMs(6) / 7;
}

function getMs(value) {
  return value * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[How do I get a weekday 12 weeks ago](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/110x2nWrU969dz6O9UuP6nLw950ugJccGhbihiW8LMx4/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks for your feedback.
I've just sent a request to access the file.

Comment: @ThomasKristiansen Was it of use?

Comment: @ThomasKristiansen Example file is accessible.

Comment: Yeah, that are perfect!
Thanks!